# Install gcc offline

Tags: linux, gcc, redhat

I am trying to install gcc offline on a RHEL 6 server.

The server cannot have internet access for security reasons. I do have the ability to do a secure file transfer to bring files onto the system.

Is there any way of downloading the gcc rpm and all the dependencies' rpm's and transfer those over to do an install? I haven't been able to find a way to do this as yet but I can't imagine that this hasn't been done before.

Comment: This seems to be a system administration issue, not a [programming](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) one, since it's asking about the *installation* of gcc RPMs (not *usage* of the programs that they contain).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [How do I find package URLs with Yum?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85715/how-do-i-find-package-urls-with-yum)?

Answer (score 0):

Create repository for RHEL6 ISO and gcc is in-build in ISO. after install using yum to resolve dependency automatically.

`yum install gcc`